# json decode won't work on string with array

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to import something from an .xml file that I have no control over. Everything went fine until the content:encoded part.

I'm getting the xml like this to strip it of the CDATA Tags:
$xml_object = simplexml_load_file($file,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

The  looks like this, I'm trying to get rid of all the tags and just get the "contents.body" parts, but when I try to use json_decode($itemJson); it returns null. What should I do?

```
[{
    "id": 34543,
    "type": "0",
    "order": 0,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 67.82337662337663,
    "data": {
        "areaMargin": 120,
        "contentWidthOriginalPx": 760
    },
    "areas": [{
        "id": 345654,
        "order": 0,
        "contents": [{
            "type": "media",
            "data": [{
                "type": "width",
                "value": "1540"
            }, {
                "type": "height",
                "value": "1026"
            }, {
                "type": "videoSrc",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "src",
                "value": "https://link.com/1567819/98/eipej334.jpg"
            }, {
                "type": "alt",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "mirror",
                "value": "false"
            }, {
                "type": "zoom",
                "value": "100"
            }, {
                "type": "rotate",
                "value": "0"
            }, {
                "type": "positiony",
                "value": "50"
            }, {
                "type": "positionx",
                "value": "50"
            }, {
                "type": "url",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "borderradius",
                "value": "0"
            }, {
                "type": "sticky",
                "value": "false"
            }, {
                "type": "metapic",
                "value": "{\"id\":0,\"tags\":{}}"
            }]
        }],
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "widthHeightRatioContent": 1.50097,
        "widthHeightRatio": 1.47442
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2131656668,
    "type": "0",
    "order": 1,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 67.82337662337663,
    "data": {
        "areaMargin": 120,
        "contentWidthOriginalPx": 760
    },
    "areas": [{
        "id": 1650030480,
        "order": 0,
        "contents": [{
            "type": "media",
            "data": [{
                "type": "width",
                "value": "1540"
            }, {
                "type": "height",
                "value": "1026"
            }, {
                "type": "videoSrc",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "src",
                "value": "https://links.com/jf/819/156722819/34/343.jpg"
            }, {
                "type": "alt",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "mirror",
                "value": "false"
            }, {
                "type": "zoom",
                "value": "100"
            }, {
                "type": "rotate",
                "value": "0"
            }, {
                "type": "positiony",
                "value": "50"
            }, {
                "type": "positionx",
                "value": "50"
            }, {
                "type": "url",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "type": "borderradius",
                "value": "0"
            }, {
                "type": "sticky",
                "value": "false"
            }, {
                "type": "metapic",
                "value": "{\"id\":0,\"tags\":{}}"
            }]
        }],
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "widthHeightRatioContent": 1.50097,
        "widthHeightRatio": 1.47442
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1740427509,
    "type": "0",
    "order": 2,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 55,
    "data": {
        "areaMargin": 120,
        "contentWidthOriginalPx": 760
    },
    "areas": [{
        "id": 802708308,
        "order": 0,
        "contents": [{
            "type": "body",
            "data": [{
                "type": "src",
                "value": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>"
            }, {
                "type": "html",
                "value": "false"
            }]
        }],
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "widthHeightRatioContent": 1.85874,
        "widthHeightRatio": 1.81818
    }]
}, {
    "id": 79506641,
    "type": "0",
    "order": 3,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 55,
    "data": {
        "areaMargin": 120,
        "contentWidthOriginalPx": 760
    },
    "areas": [{
        "id": 28476702,
        "order": 0,
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "widthHeightRatioContent": 1.85874,
        "widthHeightRatio": 1.81818,
        "contents": [{
            "type": "body",
            "data": [{
                "type": "src",
                "value": "<p><span style="\
                "font-weight:"
                bold;\
                "="
                "><br></span></p><span style="\
                "font-weight:"
                bold;\
                "="
                ">lorem upisn? </span>"
            }, {
                "type": "html",
                "value": "false"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This is no valid JSON string. Paste into a parser. The EOL with '\' are javaScript, not JSON.

Comment: @MarkusZeller and AbraCadaver thank you! I see now it throws an error. Unfortunately I can't change the origin (it's an export function for files from a third party). Any suggestions to how I can make it work in php ? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Blame the author. Do not even think of parsing wrong standardized data structures.

Comment: You should deal with bad data the way you deal with any other faulty goods. If you paid for it, ask for your money back; if not, chuck it in the bin. Unless it's so valuable to you that you are prepared to spend a lot of money repairing it.

Comment: I see, that's bad news. Thanks anyways for your help, all of you!